# Is it possible to hide a method parameter in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, methods

Is it possible to hide some parameters on a method, such as optional parameters for a recursive function that a user should never set?

I'm thinking no, so to work around that, is it normal practice to put those functions into non-static classes and keep track of things we want to hide in private variables of the instantiated class?

Just for completeness, I want to hide the last two parmeters:

```
    <Extension>
Public Function ToXmlDoc(key As Win32.RegistryKey,
                            Optional exportOptions As ExportOptions = ExportOptions.Recursive,
                            Optional regValueOptions As Win32.RegistryValueOptions = Win32.RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames,
                            Optional useEmptyValues As Boolean = False,
                            Optional xDoc As Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing,
                            Optional xParentNode As Xml.XmlNode = Nothing) As XmlDocument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an `internal` or `private` version of the function/method with the parameter. Other than that, no you can only make *Optional Parameters* which everyone who has access can see

---

**Additional Resources**

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> - `public` The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
> - `private` The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct.
> - `protected` The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class, or in a class that is derived from that class.
> - `internal` The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.
> - `protected internal` The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived
>     class in another assembly.
> - `private protected` The type or member can be accessed only within its declaring assembly, by code in the same class or in a type that is
>     derived from that class.

---

**Vb documentation here**

[Access Levels in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/access-levels)

---

**Lastly** if you don't want C# answers please don't use the tag

Comment: Thanks for the response, and C# is ok.